# How to auto archive only subfolder from outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

try to add as mentioned below, but it's not working.

subfolder --> properties --> autoArchive tab --> archive this folder

Any suggestions

Comment: Please can you add more details to your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure your Auto Archive settings for your subfolder, for example:

   [image]
2. Check the Auto Archive settings of your parent folder and set it as **do not archive**
   [image]
3. Enable Auto Archive feature via **File>Options>Advanced>AutoArchive**
   [image]
4. Try your Auto Archive settings and see if it could work as you wish. **File>Info>Mailbox Setting>CleanUpOldItems**

   [image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.